# Closed set of ordinals

Tags: set-theory

Let $\alpha$ an ordinal and $A\subseteq\alpha$. We say that $A$ is closed in $\alpha$ iff for all $\gamma<\alpha$ we have that
$$
\bigcup(A\cap\gamma)\in A
$$ 
I need prove that $A$ is closed iff for any limit ordinal $\gamma<\alpha$ and for each strictly increasing sequence $\{\alpha_\tau\}_{\tau<\gamma}\subseteq A$ we have  that $\sup_{\tau<\gamma}\alpha_\tau\in A$.

The ($\Rightarrow$) direction is done. Can someone give me a hint for solve the another direction?

**Edit:** This is the excercise. The book is "Constructability" of Devlin.
[image]

Comment: This can't be right. Take $\alpha$ to be $\omega_1$ and take $A=\omega_1\setminus\omega$. It is not hard to prove that it is closed, but $\bigcup(A\cap\omega)\notin A$. The same applies to the second definition. What you should require in both is that $\gamma$ is a *limit point* of $A$.

Comment: Yes, now read what you wrote and what the screenshot you posted reads.

Comment: @AsafKaragila See my edit, maybe I have a misunderstanding

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, I see my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the first definition of closed, as you copy it also contains a typo in the book and it should also require that $A\cap\gamma$ is unbounded in $\gamma$. (A long long time ago someone warned me about the many typos in Devlin's book. So proceed with care, and always triple-check things which seem odd.)

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila, I will be careful with the book. You know if exists some "erratum"?

Comment: No idea about that. Google might know better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for every limit ordinal $\gamma$ and for each strictly increasing sequence $\{\alpha_\tau\}_{\tau < \gamma} \subseteq A$ we have $\sup_{\tau<\gamma}{\alpha_\tau} \in A$.

Suppose $\beta < \alpha$ is arbitrary. We wish to show that 
$$ \sup(A \cap \beta) = \bigcup{(A \cap \beta)} \in A$$
Now, $A\cap \beta$ has order type $\leq \beta$, say $\gamma$. Then $\gamma < \alpha$, and the elements of $A\cap \beta$ can be enumerated as a strictly increasing sequence $\{\alpha_\tau\}_{\tau < \gamma} \subseteq A$. Then 
$$ \sup_{\tau< \gamma}{\alpha_\tau} = \sup(A\cap \beta) = \bigcup(A\cap \beta) \in A$$

Comment: Note that neither of these is the definition of a closed set, by the way.